# Login using PHP to protect from downloading a file

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication

Can I use PHP to protect someone from downloading a file unless he enters a username and password just like the sample image?

sample: http://up.iranblog.com/images/f1ufuir6kl8srq4ww4.jpg

Comment: Without trying to be rude, try using google translator to format the question in English that's actually easy to understand so someone can decipher what you actually want.

Comment: wtf are you talking about????

Comment: Don’t feel offended, but as you seem to have some problems with English, you should try [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) to improve your question.

Comment: @Tim: Or should it be: “How can I use PHP to download a file .zip from another server which asks me for username/password authentication?”

Answer (score 3):

If you want to protect filedownload you could go with the following code. All files in the file folder will be protected. This is an extremly basic example and has a lot of flaws, but it might point you in the right direction.

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/file/(.*)   /handleFiles.php?path=$1  [L]
```

handleFiles.php

```
<?
$auth = 0;
if (!isset($PHP_AUTH_USER))
{
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Login"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    print "you need to login";
    exit;
}
else
{
    if ($PHP_AUTH_USER == "UserName" and $PHP_AUTH_PW == "Password")
    {
        $auth=1;
        $file = implode('', file('/file/'.$path);
        print $file;
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Login"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        print "you need to login";
        exit;
    }
}

if ($auth==0) {
    print "you need to login";
    exit;
}
```

?>

Comment: where are *PHP_AUTH_USER , PHP_AUTH_PW* , being set ? I mean, how can the user login ?

Comment: when you send the `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Login"` header, your browser will show a pop-up requesting username and password. This will be posted as `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `PHP_AUTH_PW`. But as mentioned it is very basic. Passwords are visible in cleartext if you get access to the request headers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use PHP to download a ZIP file from another server which asks for authentication, try the following:

```
<?php

copy("http://username:password@domain.com/path/to/file.zip", "./file.zip");

?>
```